# Indicating a ObjC category in a method's return type

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category, instancetype

If I have a category on a class, and I write a constructor that returns the type but without the category mentioned, shouldn't Xcode flag that with a warning?

```
@implementation NSDate (MyBigDates)     
+ (NSDate*) bigFubarDate {

}

// versus:
+ (NSDate(MyBigDates) *) bigFubarDate {

}
// or better:
+ (instancetype) bigFubarDate {

}
```

Because the object returned has `NSDate`'s method *plus* `MyBigDates`'s.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of ObjC is that *every* `NSDate` in your program has these methods, including those created by other means. Including those that you didn't create.* Methods in categories are added to the class as part of the startup process, before nearly everything else.

This being the case, there is no notation for "NSDate with those methods", because there's no distinction.

---

*Which is why it's important to prefix methods you add to framework classes.

Comment: Then why use instancetype, or even [[[self class] alloc] init]?

Comment: @fff444 `instancetype` says "an instance of this class or subclass". Nothing categorical about it.  Similarly, using `self` in class methods gives subclassers the opportunity to override the invoked method.